# What does the return bool mean in onTouchBegan() of cocos2dx

Tags: c++, events, cocos2d-x

I find following code will only work with `onTouchBegan()` and not `onTouchMoved()` and `onTouchEnded()`

```
auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

listener->onTouchBegan = [=](Touch *touch, Event *event) {
    CCLOG("on touch begain at (%f,%f)", touch->getLocation().x, touch->getLocation().y);
    return false; // this will make following two events couldn't be fired.
};
listener->onTouchMoved = [=](Touch *touch, Event *event) {
    CCLOG("on touch moved at (%f, %f)", touch->getLocation().x, touch->getLocation().y);
};

listener->onTouchEnded = [=](Touch *touch, Event * event) {
    CCLOG("on touch ended at (%f,%f)", touch->getLocation().x, touch->getLocation().y);
};

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(listener, 1);
```

The reason why this happens is that the `onTouchBegan` assigned to a lambda function that returns `false` after changing this to `true`, `onTouchMoved` and `onTouchEnded` will be triggered as expected.

I searched around could find any explanation about what does this return flags intended to do? could some one help to explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation does not tell this, but the [programmers-guide](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/event_dispatch/index.html#touch-events) does:

```
// trigger when you push down
listener1->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    // your code
    return true; // if you are consuming it
};
```

So with the bool you can tell the system if you want to handle the touch event or not.

Also: you don't need any captures in your lambdas so better use `[]` instead of `[=]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation, I have read this doc and I thought it was only for the `onTouchBegan` action, never thought it should affect the other two consumers in the same listener. And I am aware of the usage of `[]` and `[=]` but thanks for reminding that, I think it's more like a performance thing, right? thanks

Comment: Not only performance but also usage! Depends on what you want to do with the data in the lamda. I'm not sure though if the compiler optimizes away the capture if you don't use any captured items.

Comment: shouldnt it always be returned as true ? what is a case for it to be returned as false ?

Comment: For the case you don't want to handle the touch event at the moment.
maybe your character in the game was stunned or currently there is a video playing. There are countless possibilities